# Commerce product fields as optional attributes

Tags: 7, entities, commerce

I'm trying to create some kind of product attributes by adding fields in manage fields in Store | Product types. Is there any solution to give product creator ability to select which fields he want to use when adding product. Creating product types containing all possible situations would be strange.
Example:
I create one customizable product, but I want to give it 4 various attributes. For another creating product I could select checkboxes for different attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to group products that a similar into the same product types and setup different product types, instead of having a single multipurpose product type that can be turned into anything. The product creator can decide which fields to use by choosing which product type to use. A distinction that will come very naturally for non technical people.

Comment: Not exactly. If I would like to create product types with all specified parameters then I will get something about 150 various product types combinations. All I need is one product type with additional fields ability. I can buy product A with specified width and length and then add various elements to it depending on this length and width - price will be dependent from this selected additional features.